# I have to pull the connector out partly to get stereo sound

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, alsa, pulse-audio

Using headphones, I have to pull the headphone jack partly out of the socket to get stereo sound. If I push it in all the way, only the right channel comes through. I'm assuming that this has to do with mismatched tips/rings/sleeves on the socket and the plug. I haven't been able to figure out anything more specific than that. Is there any way to reconfigure the channels in the software to make stereo work? If not, is there some kind of adapter I can use to make it work?

Thanks!

evamvid

Comment: What size is the socket? What size is the plug (a.k.a. Jack)? Are you using any adapters?

Comment: jack-socket mismatch?

Comment: 3.5mm, no adapters. I meant TRS/TRRS incompatibility when I said jack-socket mismatch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is consistent, one channel from the source is not working. It could be the amplifier but probably is a bad/broken headphone jack.
When you pull out the jack partway, one contact in the jack contacts both left and right on the headphone plug. That makes it seem like both channels are working, although if you listen carefully it would not be stereo.

Comment: Stereo is TRS..

Comment: I should mention that I have two headphone jacks, and I tried both of them with multiple headsets, with the same results. I'm thinking it could be software; I had a long drive and the problem happened after me/laptop/headphones came back.

Comment: But if it was the amp, it would make sense that it didn't work in either jack. If that was the case, would there be anything that I (or a computer shop) could do about it?

Comment: I assume you checked the settings in and tried "Test Sound" in the sound control panel (in System Settings). Beyond that, you would need some audio test/function that does not rely on the current OS to pinpoint a hardware problem. BTW, are there internal speakers? You don't mention that.

Comment: Also can you use function keys to adjust the volume? On some laptops this makes a sound. This function would be basic to the hardware and BIOS.

Comment: for me, using fn keys for volume has a sound made by ubuntu, and it didn't work before.

Comment: Strange update; I reinstalled linux-sound-base and alsa-mixer twice and it just kinda started working. In full stereo, without moving the jack around.

Comment: So I think it was a software problem.